# Should I use return before resolve / reject in ES6 Promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Is it more correct to use **return** when calling resolve / reject for an ES6 promise? Does this help with the call stack?

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {           
this._mariadb.query(...,
    (err, rows) => {             
            if (err) {return reject(err);}                
            if (rows.info.numRows > 0) {return resolve(true);}        
            return resolve(false);                
        });            
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The return value isn't used but it can be a quick way to exit the function early. That's all. The code you have above could be written to function the exact same way without return

```
if (err)
  reject(err);
else if (rows.info.numRows > 0)
  resolve(true);
else
  resolve(false);
```

Or even better

```
if (err)
  reject(err);
else
  resolve(rows.info.numRows > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

`return reject(err)` is just a more concise (but also more confusing) way to say `reject(err); return`. The argument of the `Promise` ("executor") isn't supposed to return anything meaningful, so no, it's doesn't matter if you use `return` or not.

Answer (score -1):

No, you shouldn't because once promise is resolved/rejected it is never change state